# File created via Storage Access Framework shows up as 0 bytes in size, but it's not empty and can be opened properly

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I've created a JPEG file using SAF like so:

```
public int createPublicFile(String fileName, String subfolder, String mimeType) {
        Uri parentUri = folderForImagesUri(); // Obtained earlier via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE    
        DocumentFile folder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, parentUri);
        DocumentFile subfolderUri = TextUtils.isEmpty(subfolder) ? folder : folder.createDirectory(subfolder);
        DocumentFile file = subfolderUri.createFile(mimeType, fileName);
        ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(file.getUri(), "rw");
        return descriptor.detachFd();
    }
```

The file descriptor was then passed to a native library that has written JPEG data into this fd with `write()` and closed it with `close()`. The MIME type I specified is `"image/jpeg"`.

Here's the problem: the built-in Android 11 "Files" app shows it as 0 bytes in size, and yet the file seems well-formed since I can open it by tapping, the thumbnail is also generated correctly. Why is it showing as 0 B, did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you navigate via sdk_gphone.... to the file. Same result?

Comment: Any luck on this one ?

Comment: @Louis: if I remember correctly, this only happens on an emulator and doesn't happen on any of the bunch of real devices I tried.